# Can I compare forecasting performance of rolling window VAR and usual forecast of model with ARIMA errors?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, vector-autoregression, model-comparison

Can I compare forecasting performance of rolling window VAR and usual forecast of model with ARIMA errors?
Or maybe there is exist better way to compare forecasting performance?

Comment: If you are forecasting the same target variable, then of course you can compute errors for both forecasts and compare them. What is your question?

Comment: How do you define *usual forecast of model with ARIMA errors*?